# Unable to decode base64 from req.header.authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64

In express I am grabbing the basic auth from:

```
req.headers.authorization
```

From that I get back

```
dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

I say "hey that looks like base64". I quickly go to one of those [base64 sites](https://www.base64decode.org/) and decode it and it turns out to be '`username:password`'. So I google how to decode base64 in express 4. I wind up with this code:

```
console.log(new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.toString(), 'base64').toString('ascii'));
```

That is returning:

```
+"qUMI95iAMM]=I
```

Which is not `username:password`. I also tried this with the `utf8` setting and that did not work either. I also tried this without `toString()` on the `req.headers.authorization`. How do I properly decode base64 with expressjs?

Comment: It works just fine for me: `console.log(new Buffer('dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'base64').toString('ascii'));` outputs: `username:password`. Also, you don't need `.toString()` on a value that is already a string.

Answer (score 14):

Using the new Buffer API it is now

```
console.log(Buffer.from(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1], 'base64').toString())
```

Else you will get deprecated warnings.

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone is as stupid as I am and didn't realize that the string that is returned from `req.headers.authorization` is the word `Basic` followed by the base64 encoded string, you must split the string before decoding.

```
console.log(new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1], 'base64').toString())
```

`req.headers.authorization` returned for me: `Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`. Not just the base64 string.

Comment: "new Buffer" has been deprecated, use, "Buffer.from"